# Printer-friendly web framework for CV creation?

Tags: web-development, printing

I have been looking for a framework like Bootstrap and Foundation in order to create my CV. For this reason I need something that plays well with print versions.

Is there a web framework out there that is not tailored solely on electronic devices?

Comment: Do you need the web version as well?

Comment: @xuhdev yes. The idea is to have it hosted somewhere but be able to print it if wanted without any screw-ups.

Comment: How about printing to PDF after creating the web version? I also know an example but not sure how he made it (CV of the author of Notepad++): https://donho.github.io/   Note there is a print version link on the upright corner.